# Oracle : V$TEMPFILE vs DBA_TEMP_FILES

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

`V$TEMPFILE vs DBA_TEMP_FILES`? What is difference between these two views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer on Stack Exchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/whats-the-difference-between-a-v-view-and-its-dba-equivalent

But the gist is that v$ views are sourced from control files and other instance parameters whereas dba_ views are obtained from the Data Dictionary.

Comment: Just o short note. v$ views are also accessible when database is MOUNTed status. While dba_ view are not.

Comment: (g)v$ views are from the biggest part just mapped memory structures of the Oracle instance(s), perhaps something could be from control files (like backup info) but otherwise control files are not involved.